# Asp.net Web Forms, test if two pages are the same object

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, webforms

While tracing down an issue and reading logs, I've noticed that the OnUnload method appear to be called twice for a page in some cases which may be causing the issue (based on all other parts of the page life cycle being monitored only being called once).  I was wondering if there is some value I could put into the logs that would identify if it is the same page having the OnUnload being called.

Standard object comparison will not work because certain values of the object are being changed between calls (perhaps cause the issue I've been tracking).  Even some unsafe code does not work all the time.

```
unsafe
    {
        object page = this;
        TypedReference tr = __makeref(page);
        IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
        pointerValue = ptr.ToString();
    }
```

Logging `pointerValue` in the OnLoad and OnUnload events for the same page only results in matching some of the times (~40% from eyeballing the logs).

Is there some way to definitely tell if I'm dealing with the same page object?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is working correctly.   I wired it up like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unsafe
    {
        object page = this;
        TypedReference tr = __makeref(page);
        IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LOADING: " + ptr.ToString());
    }
}

protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unsafe
    {
        object page = this;
        TypedReference tr = __makeref(page);
        IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UNLOADING: " + ptr.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I refreshed the page several times, the pointers matched:

```
LOADING: 284338068
UNLOADING: 284338068
LOADING: 352437184
UNLOADING: 352437184
LOADING: 284504276
UNLOADING: 284504276
LOADING: 352665628
UNLOADING: 352665628
LOADING: 284988092
UNLOADING: 284988092
```

You understand it's the page object at the server that is unloading after the page is rendered and sent to the client...right?  It's not the client unloading.

Comment: Would there be any reason that I am only sometimes getting matches?  I'm assuming managed memory means that the objects could be being moved around.  The cases where they match tend to be .15 seconds between events and the cases where they don't seem to be .55 seconds between events.  Edit: Right after saying this I find a log where the .15 second isn't the same but the .55 second is.

Comment: A Guess:  If you are loading the page twice, it will unload twice and it is possible that if one page takes a lot longer than the other, the load/unload events could overlap.